# NullReferenceException al pasar valor de parametro por metodo get desde funcion JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, aplicación-web

Necesito pasar un valor por metodo `get`. 
En la página de incio tengo [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)

```
 function redirectDetail() {
    location.href ='detailrestaurant.aspx?id=' + 40;
 }
```

En la otra página tengo [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net)

```
<%
        int idrestaurant = 0;

        if (Request.QueryString.Keys.Count == 0)
        {//AQUÍ EL ERROR
            int.TryParse(Session["idrestaurant"].ToString(), out idrestaurant);
        }
        else
        {
            int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString(), out idrestaurant);
        }

        Session["idrestaurant"] = idrestaurant;
   %>
```

y me genera este error

> **Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.NullReferenceException' en App_Web_detailrestaurant.aspx.b5f35768.evofi7at.dll pero no se
>   controló en el código del usuario**

¿Qué será lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Debes verificar que tengas una entrada valida en tu objeto Session, al llamar al ToString de un objeto null tienes esa exception.

Comment: Es verdad..Pero no es null ...fijate la funcion JavaScript en el inicio de la pregunta!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema de la referencia nula se da en este comando: `Session["idrestaurant"].ToString()` porque según veo en código aun no tienes definida esta variable de session.

En todo caso, intenta capturar los parametros GET de esta forma:

```
    string miVariableGet = "";

    if (Request.QueryString["id"] == null){
       //La variable 'id' es nula
    }else{
        //Se logro capturar el parametro y lo puedes utilizar. Por ejemplo
        miVariableGet = Request.QueryString["id"];   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes siempre esperar que sea nulo, dado que podrian no mandarte nada en la cadena de consulta o no haber nada en la sesion(sesion perdida).

```
<%
        int idrestaurant = 0;
        var rawValue = "";

        if (Request.QueryString?.Keys.Count == 0)
        {//AQUI EL ERROR
            rawValue = Session["idrestaurant"];                  
        }
        else
        {            
            rawValue = Request.QueryString["id"];        
        }

        if(rawValue !=null){
                 int.TryParse(rawValue.ToString(), out idrestaurant);
        }                    

        Session["idrestaurant"] = idrestaurant;
         %>
```

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es por que entra ..si en lafuncion JavaScript le paso un parametro el Request.QueryString.Keys.Cout no es igual a cero

Comment: Puedes poner un watcher en Request.QueryString o un breakpoint? y tal vez si tienes una exception incluir el Stacktrace en la pregunta.

Comment: el error esta aqui debido a que el Keys.Count es igual a 0          function redirectDetail() {
  
          location.href ='detailrestaurant.aspx?id=' + 40;
      }

Comment: En el navegador usando las developer tools puedes ver los detalles de tu request? Para saber lo que estas enviando exactamente?

Comment: GET 
http://localhost:63715/Delivery/detailrestaurant.aspx 
POST 
XHR 
http://localhost:59051/77805154045d4e8dbe81bac99c60a8b5/browserLinkSignalR/abort

Comment: Si analizas tu request, deberia lucir asi [imagen de ejemplo](http://i.imgur.com/NwTgOQ9.png) , y en querystring puedes ver que reconoce el valor que trato de pasarle